# Is it possible to retrieve token decimals via API call?

Tags: ether, tokens, etherscan

I'm looking for a way to retrieve token decimals by programmatically. Let's take this [Arcade (ARC) token](https://etherscan.io/token/0xac709fcb44a43c35f0da4e3163b117a17f3770f5). Token Decimals is `18`.

It seems etherscan does't provide API for this purpose. Is there a way to retrieve token decimals somehow?

Answer (score 3):

I have checked the contract source code and it has a public variable `decimals`. This means the contract has a public function with the same name which returns the value.

EDIT: It seems Etherscan does not provide an API to access the token info, however I found another free service called ethplorer which provides it through HTTP : https://github.com/EverexIO/Ethplorer/wiki/Ethplorer-API?from=etop#get-token-info

Comment: @lunc, can I retrieve this value via HTTP GET request?

Comment: Please see my edit.